# UNO, WASM: How to use webpack

Tags: webpack, webassembly, uno-platform

I am working on a VS Code Extension and want to use Uno Platform to create the UI for the extension.

I have started by creating a new Typescript extension with the Yo generator.  It creates a webpack config file as expected.  I then used the Uno VS Code extension to create a WASM-only project.  I have gotten the webpack config setup to include the package folder created by Dotnet when building the WASM.  Unfortunately, now webpack is complaining about not having loaders for .clr and .pdb files, which I have no solution for.

What is the correct way to place an Uno WASM package into this Extension?

Comment: Maybe a workaround here would be that during the `activate` of your extension you start a minimal http server, so you could load your application in the webview using it.